# MS Access oledb connection open "Unspecified error" error message

Tags: c#, oledb, ms-jet-ace

I have this weird error that I cannot seem to figure out. I have a Windows server 2012 Web server (IIS8.5, & .Net Framework 4.5) hosting many asp.net sites, and MS Access database .mdb is used at all the sites. For on opening new connection during busy hour, one or more of the hosted web-sites/systems' Try Catch block catches the exception with message: Unspecified Error.  We did not find any other error message at the website log. Once this exception occurred it did not matter whichever webpage is accessing the Access Database, the website is still up, but it cannot open new db connection and will continue to throw the same exception message. All Access databases are Compacted & Repaired already, but this error still occurs.

I have read and read online and can’t find anything that applies to me. Any ideas on what might be causing it, or how to fix it? Let me know if there is any more information that could be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Error message at website log file: Unspecified error

**OS**: Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit, with IIS8.5, & .Net Framework 4.5.

**MS Access**: MS Access 2003

**Connection string**: strConnection = "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;Data Source=C:\Website\db\LocalFile.mdb;Password=;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:System database=;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Extended Properties=;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=;Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;User ID=Admin;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False"

**Note**: our website C# application is running 32-bit compatible mode go well with 64-bit OS version. The websites are working fine during 99% times, except above wired problem when site's busy.

Thanks,

Leon

Comment: I would try to remove all those _Jet OLEDB:_ keys leaving only the essential and check if the connection works. Then add it back one by one to see when the error reappears

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedback. Website & its connection string is working fine during 99% times, except above wired problem from time to time when site is busy.

Comment: I would consider to upgrade MS-Access to Sql Server. Unless you have a lot of VBA code tied directly into the db you should not have a lot of hard times to upgrade. There is also a specific tool to import into Sql Server. I say this not because I don't support using MS-Access but probably in a web scenario with many concurrent access it is better to use a db with more power in this context.

Comment: Hi, Steve, Thanks.